# Swift using enums to object value to conditionally set UIImageView.image

Tags: swift, enums

I want to use an enum that has 10 cases that should correspond to 10 different weather conditions. If the string value of an object matches one of the enums, a `UIImageView.image` is set with the appropriate value. Some of the string keys have dashes to separate them too.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: If you add some code for understanding then it would be great...

Comment: Create an enum with 10 cases, check them with `switch` and set the `image`. Btw, there is no `UIImage.image`. I believe its a typo of `UIImageView.image`, right?

Comment: Yes, updated to UIImageView

Comment: can you rename the images to match the rawValues of the enum? if not set the image name as the rawValue.

Comment: Sure, but I have to match them to a JSON value: type: "cloudy-day" for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd so something like this

```
enum Weather: String {
    case temperature
    case atmosphericPressure = "atmospheric_pressure"
    case wind

    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you have the image in assets, you can use the rawValue directly

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this way to

```
enum Weather : String {
    case  temperature, atmospheric_pressure, wind, humidity, precipitation,cloudiness
    func displayImage()->String {
        switch self {
        case .temperature:
            return "temperature.png"
        case .atmospheric_pressure:
            return "atmospheric_pressure.png"
        case .wind:
            return "wind.png"
        case .humidity:
            return "humidity.png"
        case .precipitation:
            return "precipitation.png"
        case .cloudiness:
            return "cloudiness.png"
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ibOutletButton: UIButton!
    var weather = Weather.temperature
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
         imageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: weather.displayImage())
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the underscore in the enum work the same as a - in the key? (key="atmospheric-pressure") == "atmospheric_pressure"?

Comment: you can make use of the rawValue instead of the switch

Comment: you point right when same name of images and condition, switch gives more code readability and  if there is difference in case and image names.